# scrolling like the Phone app of Lollipop?

Tags: android

UI has 3 layers

1. Search bar
2. Recent phone
3. Tabs & Viewpager of the contacts

I have successfully scrolled "search bar" using this [link](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) but I want to scroll the "recent phone" first and then "search bar" later on "Tabs & Viewpager of the contacts",similar like phone gap.

Any help or link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a tip, (if you are pro developer)

*https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/dialer/widget/OverlappingPaneLayout.java*

Above link is custom layout used by lollipop phone app. This layout will work only in lollipop phone, because they are using lollipop specific apis like `nestedscrolling` etc.

Summary how android phone app using this layout ([layout link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-5.0.2_r1/res/layout/lists_fragment.xml)):

```
<com.android.dialer.widget.OverlappingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lists_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

    <ListView>
        ...//Top pane
        ...// In phone app they show recently dialed number, which gets clipped when scrolled.
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout>
       // bottom pane
       <ViewPagerTab></ViewPagerTab> // phone app's viewPager tab
       <ListView></ListView>         // below a list view
    </FrameLayout>

</com.android.dialer.widget.OverlappingPaneLayout>
```

In activity code ([code link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/dialer/list/ListsFragment.java)):

```
private void setupPaneLayout(OverlappingPaneLayout paneLayout) {
    // TODO: Remove the notion of a capturable view. The entire view be slideable, once
    // the framework better supports nested scrolling. paneLayout.setCapturableView(mViewPagerTabs);
    paneLayout.openPane();
    paneLayout.setPanelSlideCallbacks(mPanelSlideCallbacks);
    paneLayout.setIntermediatePinnedOffset(

    LayoutTransition transition = paneLayout.getLayoutTransition();
    // Turns on animations for all types of layout changes so that they occur for
    // height changes.
    transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
}
```

Comment: @vakman.Thanks for reply.could you please provide a demo of this.

Comment: @vakman.I tried this demo from sdk,but its a sliding layout from corners.I need a sliding like phone app

Comment: @Swati, sdk code is different,which is SlidingPaneLayout. The above link is the actual layout used in lollipop phone app.